# How to change input shape for LogisticRegression fit function?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am trying to apply LogisticRegression to my dataset.

I have split the data into train, test, and validation. Data is normalized with one hot encoding. I am getting

```
ValueError: bad input shape (527, 2)
```

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

#read the data
train_data = pd.read_csv('ip2ttt_train.data',header=None)
test_data = pd.read_csv('ip2ttt_test.data', header=None)
valid_data = pd.read_csv('ip2ttt_valid.data', header=None)

#for valid dataset
valid_label = valid_data[9]
valid_features = valid_data.drop(columns =9) 

#for test dataset
test_label = test_data[9] 
test_features = test_data.drop(columns =9)

#for train dataset
train_label = train_data[9] 
train_features = train_data.drop(columns =9)

X_valid = pd.get_dummies(valid_features)
y_valid = pd.get_dummies(valid_label)

X_test = pd.get_dummies(test_features)
y_test = pd.get_dummies(test_label)

X_train = pd.get_dummies(train_features)
y_train = pd.get_dummies(train_label)

clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, multi_class='multinomial', solver='newton-cg', penalty='l2') #penalty = L1 or L2 and solver = newton-cg or lbfgs

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Here is the shape for X and y:

```
X_train.shape
(527, 27)
y_train.shape
(527, 2)
```

**What I tried:**

I found that I need to change the shape of `y_train`. I tried converting `y_train` into `np.array` and `flatten()` it but it did not work. I think I need `(527,1)` shape. I also tried `reshape([527,1])` but it gave me an error. I know that

> y: array-like of shape (n_samples,)
>
> Target vector relative to X.

but dont know how to implement it right.

**UPDATE:**
Sample data for `train_label`:

```
0      positive
1      positive
2      positive
3      positive
4      positive
         ...   
522    negative
523    negative
524    negative
525    negative
526    negative
Name: 9, Length: 527, dtype: object
```

Sample data for **train_features**

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
0   x   x   x   x   o   o   x   o   o
1   x   x   x   x   o   o   o   x   o
2   x   x   x   x   o   o   b   o   b
3   x   x   x   x   o   b   o   o   b
4   x   x   x   x   b   o   o   b   o
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
522 x   o   x   o   o   x   x   x   o
523 o   x   x   x   o   o   x   o   x
524 o   x   x   x   o   o   o   x   x
525 o   x   o   x   x   o   x   o   x
526 o   x   o   x   o   x   x   o   x
```

I tried to feed them into `fit()` without **one hot encoding**
and got error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'x'`

Comment: Please notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (since never executed) and should be omitted from questions here as it just creates unnecessary noise (edited out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Data is normalized with one hot encoding.

This should **not** be the case with scikit-learn's `LogisticRegression`; as the quoted documentation says:

> y: array-like of shape (n_samples,)
>
> Target vector relative to X.

you need a shape of `(n_samples,)` for all your labels (train, validation, test). You should **remove** all the `pd.get_dummies()` commands for defining `y_train`, `y_valid`, and `y_test`, and use respectively the `train_label`, `valid_label`, and `test_label` instead.